# Which class is being used here? C#

Tags: c#, instantiation

If I've a base class "Base" and a derived class "Derived" then which of these are ok?

```
Base b = new Base();
Derived d = new Derived();
```

(2 lines above are fine)

```
Base b = new Derived();
Derived d = new Base();
```

Do they mean anything?

Comment: You cannot assign a base instance to a variable of the derived type.  Everything else is valid.

Comment: All cows are animals but not all animals are cows.

Comment: I would highly recommend searching for and going through a polymorphism tutorial, the complete answer to this question is far too broad to fit into a simple Q&A, and a simple 'yes, xyz is okay' is clearly not going to help you out that much, either.

Comment: Why don't you simply try it? It would be faster then posting a question here. If you need docs, see this closing reason: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam"*

Answer (score 1):

@Zuzlx's comment is spot-on:

> All cows are animals but not all animals are cows.

Replace `Base` with `Animal`, and `Derived` with `Cow`, and it will become a lot clearer:

```
Animal a = new Cow();  // This works since a cow is always an animal.
Cow c = new Animal();  // Just won't work.
```

Comment: So does "Animal a = new Cow(); " create an instance of the Cow or Animal class?

Comment: It creates an instance of the `Cow` class, but you only have reference to it as an `Animal` class, which means you can only access members/methods that `Animal` makes available.  If you need to access `Cow` specific members/methods, you need to `cast` it back to `Cow`.